# Переклад слів cringe та cringy

Tags: сленг

Вітаю,

Потрібна допомога у перекладі слів `cringe` та `cringy`.

Приклад використання: `Zelensky's speech was super cringy`.

Дослівний переклад слів я, звісно ж, знаю. Мені потрібне слово (можливо сленгове), при прочитанні якого, читачу/слухачу стане зрозуміло, що мені буквально захотілось блювати.

Comment: slang - говірка

Answer (score 6):

*To cringe* [означає](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cringe) *to feel very embarrassed*:

> *I cringed at the sight of my dad dancing.*

Часто це емоційна і фізична реакція на ситуацію, в якій перебуває хтось інший, що супроводжується сильним дискомфортом і так званим [secondhand embarrassment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vicarious_embarrassment):

> ***Vicarious embarrassment*** (also known as secondhand, empathetic, or
>   third party embarrassment) is the feeling of embarrassment from
>   observing the embarrassing actions of another person. Unlike general
>   embarrassment, vicarious embarrassment is not caused by participating
>   in an embarrassing event, but instead it's caused by witnessing
>   (verbally and/or visually) another person experience an embarrassing
>   event.

Тобто, людині стає дуже ніяково від поведінки інших - і це проявляється на емоційному та фізичному рівнях. Хочеться відвернутись, скривитись, заплющити очі.

Думаю, цей *тілесний* аспект важливо передати, перекладаючи *cringe* або *cringy* українською.

Можу запропонувати такі варіанти:

> *Коли я побачив, як він танцює, мене аж **пересмикнуло**/**[пройняло](http://sum.in.ua/s/projmaty)**.*
>
> *Мене просто **верне** від його вигляду.*
>
> *Мене аж **[кидає/корчить/кривить](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)** від його слів.*

Ці варіанти можна використовувати при перекладі речень з *cringe* як іменником, *cringe* як дієсловом і з *cringy* (прикметник).

Тобто англійською можна сказати:

> *His speech was pure **cringe**.*
>
> *I **cringed** at his speech.*
>
> *His speech was so **cringy**.*

Усі ці фрази можна перекласти як:

> *Мене просто пересмикувало від кожного його слова.*

Цей переклад, звісно, повністю не передає значення оригіналу, але, думаю, все ж наближений до нього.

Comment: Дуже не погані варіанти, дякую. Копаючи, я й сам наткнувся на 'vicarious embarrassment'/`Spanish shame`. Трохи міркував над `іспанським соромом`, але `пересмикнуло` -- непоганий варіант.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk не знала про іспанський сором) Сюдячи з ґуґлу, цей вислів стосується іспанської фрази  _vergüenza ajena_ (сором від імені інших), але сам собою не дуже популярний. До речі, я теж тут раніше ставила слова у `backticks` і мені зробили зауваження) Цей формат призначений для коду, і, здається, його не можуть правильно прочитати скрінрідери. Краще користуватися _курсивом_.

Comment: @kaamos Гарні варіанти, особливо *пересмикувало*, проте воно не передає елемент сорому, а лише момент відторгнення.

Comment: @kaamos Крім того, *to cringe* можна із абсолютно усього,  не тільки поведінки і не тільки людей.

Comment: @improbable так, мої варіанти - більше про відторгнення, а не сором. Коли потрібно акцентувати увагу на другому, то ваші варіанти, звісно, підходять для цього краще) А щодо _cringe_ з усього - так, справді, тільки це вже буде інше значення слова (не те, про яке запитує автор). Можна _cringe_ від страху, від вітру, від неприємного звуку - і тут потрібен вже інший переклад (наприклад - _зіщулитися_).

Comment: @kaamos Трохи не так. Якраз від страху, від вітру, від неприємного звуку не можна *cringe*, бо як ви правильно зазначили, це вже не cringe, а зовсім інше слово. Під абсолютно всім я мав на увазі і хотів підкреслити, що від інших речей(не ті котрі ви зазначили) можна cringe, крім поведінки. Дуже часто це люди, відео(cringe compilation), абстрактні речі(ця музика крінжова), одяг і т.д. А про поєднання відторгнення/сором, саме тому цим словам немає гарних відповідників і переклад може бути лише, на жаль, суто контекстуальним.

Comment: @improbable [словник Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cringe) пропонує декілька дефініцій слова _cringe_ - в т. ч. пов'язані з реакцією на страх, холод, біль (значення 2-е та 4-е). Можливо, це були оригінальні значення слова, до того, як воно стало сленговим. У всякому разі, я вас зрозуміла і погоджуюсь, що _cringe_ (у сленговому значенні) не обов'язково стосується чиєїсь поведінки. Трішки підправила свою відповідь - не хотілося переписувати все)

Answer (score 2):

У випадку англійської мови, за більшістю слів не можна закріпляти єдиний переклад, бо, зазвичай, вони мають, як мінімум, декілька залежно від контесту і незалежно від слова.

В українській **немає гарних відповідників** цим словам.

Звертаючись до [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cringy), популярного словника сленгу та сучасної лексики, бачимо такі основні значення *cringy*(*to cringe* - відповідне дієслово):

> 1. Someone or something that makes you embarrassed to be a part of the human race. Usually classified by seeing something and feeling extremely embarrassed, throwing your head back and closing your eyes to block your view of the *cringy*..
> 2. Someone or something that is or makes you feel very awkward (embarrassed).
> 3. when you wanna drink bleach and stuff.

З власного досвіду, можу стверджувати, що, зазвичай, це слово вживають, коли говорять про відчуття екстримального сорому та/або зніяковілості за дії людини/людей або за якісь події/явища/речі, що, зазвичай, змушує людей відчувати себе незручно, так що хочеться кричати і/або крутитися на місці і/або вистрибнути у вікно і/або випити отрути і т.д.(авторська гіпербола), коли спостерігаєш ці дії/події або переживаєш/зазнаєш цих явищ/речей.

Я схильний мати декілька варінтів перекладу для англійських слів і вживати їх залежно від контесту.
Звідси, варіанти перекладу *to cringe*:

1. (сильно)Ніяковити від когось/чогось
2. Бентежитися(як синонім ніяковіти) від чогось/когось
3. Соромитися чогось/когось
4. Відчувати себе незручно від чогось/когось

Якби я вибирав лише одне - я б вибрав **ніяковіти**, оскільки про мене воно є найкращим перекладом серед вищезазначених слів, проте воно не передає той ступінь інтенсивності, котре передає оригінальне слово та не передає другу частину мого трактування, пов'язану із неприйняттям/відторгненням подій/явищ/речей від яких ніяковієш, котра є важливою частиною оригінального слова.

Щодо **cringy**, я був би схильний речення із цим словом перефразовувати, використовуючи переклад для відповідного дієслова, оскільки слово зніяковілий гірше, на мою думку, передає суть слова, оскільки те, що *cringy*, змушує людину ніяковіти постійно, а не один раз.